# Can I have custom folder icons for some specific (document) folders?

Tags: linux-mint, icons

I am using Linux Mint, with Cinnamon Desktop Environment.

I come from MacOS, and in that system I am used to set custom icons for some of the sub-folders in my documents folder. Is it possible to do the same in Linux? Maybe with some additional 'tool'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application that you refer to is the *file browser*. In cinnamon the default is called *Nemo*. You can install other, like for example *Nautilus* or *Dolphin*. Each one has its own set of features.

In *Nemo*, right click in the folder you are interested. You will see a folder icon on the left. Just click on it and the you can select an icon of your choosing.

[image]

Comment: Great! it works! thanks!

Comment: @Fabio you are welcome!